# Apache adds parameters to meta refresh url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, page-refresh

After redirecting a page with

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=https://myserver.com/category/item.php">`

the location in the browser shows https://myserver.com/category/item.php?category=item !

I'd like to remove this "?category=item" from the url.

.htaccess rewrite rule is :

`RewriteRule ^category/(.*).php  index.php?category=$1 [L]`

This issue only happens on the public shared server, not on my local Apache installation, and only after a `refresh`, despite the fact that the php script and the .htaccess rules  are exactly the same on both servers. 3 RewriteCond about SSL are automatically added to the remote .htaccess, though :

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$`

Could this be the problem ? I have the same issue with any pages (and differents rewrite rules) when I use meta refresh on this remote server.

Is there any way to prevent the server to append this parameter to the original url ?

Edit : I tried to add a `[QSD]` flag to the rewrite_rule, or a `?` after the `index.php?category=$1`, and contacted the help-desk of the web-hosting company Funio, to no avail.

Comment: Could you verify the rewrite module is enabled in your local setup?

Comment: Of course it is, I only use urls like localhost/category/item.php while browsing it ... not with parameters.

Comment: The `content` attribute in your `meta` tag is missing the opening double-quote.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it, but it is not missing in my script, so this is not the issue...